# Page doesn't load when typing url of a private component into browser's adress bar (React-router v4)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I'm making an app with authentication, using react-router and react-router-redux for handling routing. My routes get rendered as expected when I start from a non-private route, hovewer when I type a private route's url directly into the browser's adress bar nothing gets loaded(screenshot). How can I fix this problem?

PrivateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({userStatus, component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    const stuffToShow = (props) => {
        if(userStatus.authenticated) {
            return <Component {...props}/>;
        }
        return <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location }
        }}/>
    };

    return <Route exact {...rest} render={stuffToShow}/>

};

export default connectComponent(['userStatus'], PrivateRoute);
```

routes.js

```
export function renderRoutes(routes) {
    return routes.map((route, i) => {
        if(route.private) {
            return <PrivateRoute key={i} {...route} />;
        }
        return <Route key={i} {...route}/>;
    })
}

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        exact:true,
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        exact:true,
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path: '/registration',
        exact:true,
        component: Registration
    },
    {
        path: '/users/:id',
        exact:true,
        component: UserPage,
        private: true
    }, 
    {
        path: '/users',
        exact:true,
        component: Users,
        private: true
    },
    {
        path: '/goodBye',
        exact:true,
        component: Goodbye
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        component: NoMatch
    }
];
```

root:

```
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <div>
               <Header />
                <Switch>
                    {renderRoutes(routes)}
                </Switch> 
            </div>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
```

How I render html on express server:

```
        this.app.use('/api/users', userRoute);
        this.app.use('/api/blogPosts', blogPostsRoute);
        this.app.use('*',(req,res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html')));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this part:

```
const stuffToShow = (props) => {
    if(userStatus.authenticated) {
        return <Component {...props}/>;
    }
    return (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    );
};
```

The `<Redirect />` is multiple lines, should be enclosed with `()`. That's my best guess of your problem.

Comment: It works the same way with braces. I think it's most likely that the problem lies on my express server and it has something to do with how I render html. I added that part to the original post and updated the screenshot.

Comment: I do not think this is a server problem, because I noticed an error in your console. That means your javascript is in problem. Try to modify the return value of `PrivateRoute` to this and see it works or not: `return <Route exact {...rest} render={(props) => { <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }}/> }/>`

Comment: Sorry, have no idea. Unless you are willing to share the complete code via github.

Comment: Cloned your project, but could not run it. Do not know why. I noticed this in `PrivateRoute.js`: `import {connectComponent} from '../../Utils//Utils';`. Have you tried to fix it?

Comment: This just a custom function I wrote to reduce boilerplate. It simply returns a connected component. I guess you cant run it because you need mongodb installed on your pc.